# Static modifier in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, static, objective-c++

I want to make sure some knowledge about `static` in Objective-C

1. In Objective-C，the following Code is wrong, but in Objective-C++ it is right:

   ```
   static UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
   ```
2. When I use `static` modify the variable which is a pointer like the code above in a function, I find it will reserve two variable: the pointer and the object (the pointer point to), is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes C++ allows more complex static initialization than C.  The `static` keyword has nothing to do with this behaviour in either language; that just controls scope (Note: I am assuming you are not using `static` within a C++ class declaration, but within an implementation file as you would do with C/Objective-C).
2. You need to understand the concept of an object (an instance of a class) and a reference to that object.  You probably also want to understand about where, in memory, these things are stored (i.e. the heap and the stack).  Objective-C also adds complexity as it uses reference counting to manage the lifetime of objects, unlike C++ and C.